# What methods should I override to use LINQ Where, Find?

Tags: c#, linq, overriding

Here is some example code.

I have created my own class:

```
public class MyObject {
    private string _guid;
    public int Value;

    // other stuff here...        

    public MyObject() {
        _guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    }
}
```

And i have some object i created before and a list of other objects, for example:

```
MyObject inputObject = new MyObject();
List<MyObject> myObjects = new List<MyObject>();
```

I want to use them like:

```
myObjects.Where(mo => mo == inputObject).Sum(fo => fo.Value);
```

And so on. (I am sure that in my list there is an object with the same GUID as the *inputObject*, this is just the example code)

**The questions are:**

How can I use LINQ Find, Where, Sum and so on on this List?

What methods should i override to compare by GUID and how should they look like?

Is it better to use IEquatable with Equals() method?

Comment: When you check for `==` you´d need to override the `==`-operator, when you however check against `Equals` you have to override that method. For `Sum` you won´t need any overrides as you already put the value to be aggregated into the delegate.

Comment: @HimBromBeere So how should they be overridden correctly? And should I use IEquatable<T> for MyObject?

Comment: It depends on how your where-clause looks like and which method you call there. This one should be the method to override (and maybe some this method relies on as Marc pointed out).

Comment: `IEquatable<T>` (an interface with a method) is largely unrelated to `==` (an operator); if you add an `Equals(MyObject)` method and override `Equals(object)`, then implementing `IEquatable<MyObject>` is *good practice*, but it won't impact the code in the question in any way

Comment: @MarcGravell is it better to use IEquatable<T>, as in my code i compare MyObjects many times?

Comment: @Mark "better" is impossible to answer without context. Is it better *for you*? Only you can answer that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're checking with `==`, you would need to provide the `==` operator (which also means you need to provide a `!=` operator). Otherwise, reference  equality will be applied (since it is a class), and : it is unlikely that it is the **same** object (just one that is equivalent).

Alternatively, you could override `Equals` and change your test to use `.Equals` (note: also override `GetHashCode()` if you do this).

An easier option, however, might be to check the relevant  inner value directly, i.e.

```
public string Guid => _guid;
```

and:

```
.Where(mo => mo.Guid == inputObject.Guid)
```

Comment: Wouldn't `IEquatable<T>` be a better option than operator overloading? You can override `Equals()` to use the `IEquatable<T>` implementation.

Comment: @toadflakz When OP wants to compare using `==` we need to override that operator, implementing the interface won´t do anything in this scenario.

Comment: Searching by Guid is the best way here